# Is this a dumb idea for how to simplify redux + react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to refactor an app to use redux toolkit but I'm running into an infinite loop when dispatching an action to set state and I suspect its because I'm not following the conventions.

What I'm attempting to do at a high level is have a `useAppHandlers` hook that returns all the handlers for the entire app. Similarly, I have a `useAppState` hook that returns a global object with *all* my state. Snippet from [my config file](https://gist.github.com/gigamesh/6b5c89999d77f5a9ff6b168e150b9f42):

```
export const useAppState = () => {
  const coingeckoApiState: AppState[typeof coingeckoApi.reducerPath] = useSelector(state => state.coingeckoApi);
  const connectionState: AppState['connection'] = useSelector(state => state.connection);
  const currencyState: AppState['currency'] = useSelector(state => state.currency);
  return { ...coingeckoApiState, ...connectionState, ...currencyState };
};

export const useAppHandlers = () => {
  const connectionHandlers = useConnectionHandlers();
  const currencyHandlers = useCurrencyHandlers();
  return { ...connectionHandlers, ...currencyHandlers };
};
```

^^Does that look problematic? I unfortunately can't share the full repo because it's private.

In all the redux examples I've come across, people import `useDispatch` in addition to the actions they are dispatching within each component. I really don't like how it results in so many lines of code just for imports and set up ex:
`const dispatch = useDispatch()` repeated ad nauseam across the repo).

This repo is a real-world example of what I'm trying to avoid:

https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-interface/blob/4078390a4890445d1ff0ed5196fd4cb56a44de87/src/components/NavigationTabs/index.tsx#L116

Before I give up and just follow conventions, I'd like to pinpoint if the above way I'm configuring redux is the source of the infinite loops, or if its a random bug I introduced deeper in the code.

Comment: I don't think that this is the cause of your infinite loop but it is not best practice to have every single component dependant upon the entire app state. I don't *think* it is necessarily harmful though. If you can create a simplified example that demonstrates your infinite loop then I'd be happy to take a look at it. Here is an example RTK app demonstrating their Counter application: https://codesandbox.io/s/rtk-counter-sample-ly8xe

Comment: Thank you. I'll do some more testing to narrow down the problem and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, just don't. You will never be able to bundle-split in the future if the need for that arises when creating such a god-object. Also, adding something now means you have to touch at least one more file that is not using that something - same goes for deleting.

In addition to that, writing so "wide" selectors that select a full slice, even if your components only ever consume a part of that slice is a horrible thing for your performance - those components will always rerender if *anything* in that slice changes, no matter if it is important for your component.

Lastly: Just ignore your imports and let your IDE take care of it for you, probably out of the box. Your IDE can auto-import them for you. You can configure your IDE (with eslint autofix or other plugins) to automatically sort your imports alphabetically and also remove unused imports on save. I'm sure there is even a plugin that will just collapse your imports for you if you don't want to see them.

PS: as for *why* in react-redux you usually import `useDispatch` everywhere, you can read a bit on the history of that decision here: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#recipe-useactions

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm starting to realize why it's designed this way. However I'm still confused why libraries like reactn are able to get away with such a simpler API (https://github.com/CharlesStover/reactn#readme)

...I would be using that if not for its poorer typescript support and smaller developer adoption, but maybe there are other tradeoffs I'm not seeing?

Comment: I guess tradeoffs would be (I have no experience with that lib) that it seems more tightly intertwined with React components, probably less testable, you could get conflicts easily and there is no real data flow when everything could theoretically just write to state. Redux is first and foremost a data flow pattern. But all that is probably highly individual :)